# Своя рассылка на Perl

Tags: веб-программирование, perl

Всем привет! Поддерживаю сайт гостиницы. Люди бронируются на сайте, оставляют свою почту. Хотят сделать рассылку по ним предложений со скидками и т.п.
Хочу сделать свою, на Perl. Но у хостера следующие ограничения:

> Ограничения на отправку почтовых сообщений через SMTP-сервер:
>   - не более 60 писем в секунду за одно подключение к серверу;
>   - не более 100 писем суммарно за одно подключение к серверу;
>   - не более 500 писем в час с домена;
>   - не более 60 писем в минуту с одного почтового ящика;
>   - не более 500 писем в час с одного почтового ящика;
>   - не более 100 адресов-получателей одного письма;
>   - не более 32 одновременных подключений с одного IP на порт 25;
>   - не более 32 одновременных подключений с одного IP на порт 2525;
>   - максимальный размер отправляемого письма равен 25 Мб.

Не подскажете как такое лучше реализовать? sleep-ами? Как вообще всё это считать? Скрипт не будет висеть на выполнении минуту например, выдаст 500-ю, или браузер по тайм-ауту и всё закончится. Может быть пример такого кто подскажет? Хотелось бы, что бы запустил скрипт - и он всё это сам посчитал/подождал  коорче выполнил и закрылся с миром. Спасибо!

Comment: При отправке почты может быть не доступен сервер или еще что нибудь. значит требуются повторные попытки, если не удалось сразу отправить. Поэтому в любом случае делать это непосредственно в обработчике cgi, который общается с web-клиентом нельзя. cgi должен записать в какую нибудь таблицу в БД, например, что и кому надо отправить. Эта таблица будет очередью сообщений. Далее отдельный скрипт, постоянно работаютщий на срвере или запускаемый по cron должен брать из этой очереди еще не отправленное и собственно отправлять. И он может делать любые задержки, какие ему нравится